# How to use omnigroup framework in an iOS project?

Tags: iphone

I need to be able to write and read from a rtf file in iOS.

The omnigroup framework has the 2 classes i am looking for :

```
OmniUI/iPad/RTF/OUIRTFReader
OmniUI/iPad/RTF/OUIRTFWriter
```

I managed to build the frameworks but i cant figure out how to integrate theses classes in my own project.

I had the following frameworks to my project :

```
OmniAppKit.framework
OmniFoundation.framework
OmniBase.framework
```

I still get some undefined identifier such as :

```
RCS_ID("$Id$");
OBINITIALIZE
OMNI_POOL_START
```

Has anybody been able to use the omnigroup framework in your own project ?

Thanks,

Vincent

Answer (score 1):

We do need some better documentation for this, but the TextEditor example app in `OmniUI/iPad/Examples/TextEditor` may be a good starting point for seeing how we include the frameworks in our apps.

In this particular case, you may prefer to pull out the OUIRTFReader class and any dependencies it needs from OmniAppKit and OmniFoundation into your project. updating the `#imports` to be `"..."` instead of `<OmniThis/AndOmniThat.h>`.

Comment: I tried to do that but it doesn't work : the TextEditor sample code doesn't include omnigroup as frameworks but as project dependencies. I also tried yo pull out the 2 classes and add all the sources they depend on but that's also a fail, you end up pulling tenths of classes, and i didn't manage to get this working (besides that seems too dirty)

Comment: Oups, didn't notice you are actually from OmniGroup ;) So i guess you're suggestion is the proper way to do this, i will edit my question with the problems i've faced while doing that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could try following the instructions given as part of [this thread](http://forums.omnigroup.com/showthread.php?t=18516) on the Omni Group forums.  They appear to have been able to build the framework under the iOS 4.2 SDK.

I don't think you want the OmniAppKit framework, as that is just for the Mac.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, this thread is rather how to build the frameworks which i managed to do, unfortunatly they dont explain how you can use the frameworks once you've build them. I added a question on the forum.